# How do you build a capsule in EDK2 and how do you put UEFI images inside that capsule?

Tags: firmware, uefi, edk2

I am testing around with EDK2 by Tianocore (https://github.com/tianocore/edk2) and I can build BIOS images as well as UEFI Applications and drivers but when it comes to building a UEFI capsule, I am not sure how to go about doing this.

https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%20Fall%202018%20Intel%20UEFI%20Capsules.pdf this points to some ideas but I am not sure the exact path to take here.

I see two possibilities:

https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/master/FmpDevicePkg this is the package mentioned in the PDF link above and the PDF also mentions an integrated build pipeline for making a capsule. It also mentions a standalone python script which is option two.

https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/c640186ec8aae6164123ee38de6409aed69eab12/BaseTools/Source/Python/GenFds there are standalone scripts to make these images and artifacts like capsules and headers at this location but I am unsure if these are intended to be used as is or only as a part of a larger build pipeline.

My end goal here is to produce a UEFI capsule and place UEFI drivers inside it as the payload so any tips or help would be appreciated.

Comment: The capsule interface is standardised by UEFI, but what the firmware does with it is not. What is the goal here? What effect are you wanting the capsule to have in your platform?

Comment: We want a capsule that has a set of EFI images for updating already in memory drivers on the firmware and we would ideally want the capsule to be signed.

Comment: And you are in control of the firmware already running on the platform so that you can add the functionality that does this?